# How to set background color for a boxed link?

Tags: html, css

I have a link on my website with borders.
HTML:

```
<p id="hero4"><a href="menu.html">Explore our menu</a></p>
```

CSS:

```
#hero4 {
border:1px solid white;
border-radius:5px;
width:150px;
height:30px;
margin:auto;}
```

I'd like the entire "box" to turn grey when a user hovers over it, like the "create yours" button on the Starbucks website. Right now, I have:

```
#hero4 a:hover {
background-color:grey;}
```

but only the small rectangular area around the text turns grey. How can I change my CSS so the entire area within the border changes color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the style from the `<p>` into the `<a>` tag, and also set it to `display:block;`.

```css
#hero4 a {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block; /*added*/
  text-align: center; /*extra: center text horizontally*/
  line-height: 30px; /*extra: center text vertically*/
}
#hero4 a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<p id="hero4"><a href="menu.html">Explore our menu</a></p>
```

Comment: This is more appropriate as hover pointer starts from box border.

Comment: @KunJ Thanks I totally agree, otherwise it's gonna have a confusing UI.

Answer (score 6):

Then just set the hover to the `#hero4`:

```
#hero4:hover { /*removed a*/
   background-color:grey;
}
```

You can use `:hover` for any element.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use hover over for anchor tag **a**, instead use it for the paragraph tag **p**, as **p** is the parent for the anchor tag.

**Code**

```
#hero4:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6d6ro8j4/)